# VsCode как уменьшить масштаб интерфейс?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Никак не могу найти статью где было бы показано как уменьшить масштаб именно **интерфейса** *(Не <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>)*

P.S. I'm on Windows 10

Comment: кого, где, на чем?..

Comment: @МихаилРебров У меня огромные кнопки и весь интерфейс большущий из за низкого разрешения монитора и больших его размеров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла ответ, его предоставил другой человек.
Сперва с помощью клавиш CTRL + или CTRL - выбираете подходящий размер отображения окна интерфейса, а затем с помощью CTRL + колесо мыши подбираете оптимальный размер шрифта (текста кода).

Для управления увеличением/уменьшением масштаба только для текста CTRL + колесо мыши сделайте следущее:

1 Ctrl+Shift+P (или Вид->Палитра команд. )

2 Введите Открытые настройки пользователя

3 Изменить settings.json

4 Добавить "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true

5 Сохраните его.

Вы можете использовать колесико мыши для увеличения или уменьшения масштаба только текста в текстовом поле.

Answer (score 0):

Через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> интерфейс изменяет свои размеры. Иконки, текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]